# Error when trying to create Composer environment: operation timed out

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I am trying to create Cloud Composer V1 environment, tried changing to different locations, but always receive this error after 20+ minutes:

```
Composer operation timed out internal dependencies of Composer.
```

Is there a way to resolve this? What configuration do you use in order to create the environment successfully.

I tried creating Cloud Composer V1 environment with 2 different locations: asia-southeast1 and australia-southeast1

Answer (score 0):

I created an environment in the same zones you mentioned. There were no problems. I recommend creating an environment using the latest version of cloud composer and airflow (depends on location) to avoid installation errors. You can read the full documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating).

[image]